# After uninstalled extension confirmation email send

Tags: extensions, email, uninstall

Can you please tell me **how can i send confirmation email to our server if someone uninstalled our extension or package**.

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

**You can create Uninstall class for Magento 2 modules only!**

There you can send emails if someone uninstall the extension from CLI with

`magento module:uninstall {Module_Name}`

Have a look at these two pages: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/setup-scripts-magento-2/